# jQuery wait for class to be added then add class

Tags: jquery, class, listener

I want to be able to add a class to a div element but only after a class has been added to another element.

When the class '.added' has been added to a.add_to_cart_button add a new class to

```
<a class="lm-added-message"></a>
```

called 'show'.

The result:

```
<a class="added_to_cart_button added"></a>

<a class="lm-added-message show"></a>
```

I'm currently using the following but it does work:

```
jQuery(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function (e) {
    if (e.target.className == 'added') {
        jQuery(".lm-added-message").addClass("show");
    }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: So who is adding the class, if not you ?

Comment: Also, `DOMNodeInserted` strangely enough fires when a DOM Node is inserted, not just changed. You're looking for mutation observers, or rather, you should be looking for something else entirely, as there shouldn't be any need to listen for class changes.

Comment: The class gets added when an item is added to a basket. Here is the page where the action is performed: 

http://www.lindameredith.com/wp/serum/

When you click 'Add to bag' the class .added gets added to a button. At this point I want to trigger a confirmation message by adding the class .show to a hidden div. I'm not sure the best way to do this though.

Comment: Either hook into the event handler that adds the class, or just create your own event handler for the same element, rather than listening for a class being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events, the event you are searching for may be **DOMAttrModified**:
https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMAttrModified

Mutation Events are deprecated though, so it's suggested to replace them with MutationObserver:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

You must also check if className *contains* added, not *is equals to*, because you have another class too there.